# ERROR: relation "table" does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a postgres database with a specific relation but when I use below code :

```
    String format = "select * from %s;";
    String query = String.format(format, TABLE_NAME);
    Map<Long, String> Info = new HashMap<Long, String>();
    validateConnection();//check for connection
    try {
        ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            Info.put(rs.getLong(COL_NAME_ID), rs.getString(COL_NAME_INFO));
        }
        return Info;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.warn("Could not return record count for {}: {}", TABLE_NAME, e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
```

My logger say `Could not return record count for table: ERROR: relation "table" does not exist`.

But when I query using Ubuntu terminal it works fine.

what is the problem?

thanks in advance,

Comment: Which value assigned to TABLE_NAME?

Comment: The name of my table,in my DBInterface `final String TABLE_NAME= "table";`

Comment: try it:  TABLE_NAME="\"table\"";

Comment: thanks @frostjogla but it returns the same result

Comment: Which database-server you use? MSSQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL? Try connect to the your server with other programm for maintance database and check existence your table.

Comment: Naming a table "table" is just asking for trouble -- in any SQL dialect. Try it with a saner name before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your client may have a different search path. Can you try using the fully qualified table name, including schema example public.table (or similar)?

Comment: If that doesn't work, would you mind simply hard coding the SQL so you know that the "format" isn't introducing weird characters or anything like that. If all else fails, echo out the query before it gets executed and include it in your question